# Dual boot into ubuntu with windows boot manager?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

Noob here, please bear with me.
I installed Ubuntu 14 LTS on a separate partition of size 10GB and formatted it to ext4 during installation. Now it is not visible through windows.

The installation finished, was asked to reboot. The boot menu still shows only Windows. I was not asked an option like "dual boot" during ubuntu installation like some guides stated.

So right now, I installed ubuntu but dont know how to boot into it.
I searched this forum and they stated I overwrite the windows bootmanager with GRUB using the ubuntu DVD. You know how scary this is to a noob.. Everything may not go according to instructions and I may lose all data.
Along with some posts about grub errors, not able to restore etc.. So honestly I am scared.

Is there a way to simply add ubuntu option to the boot list during bootup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand how scary it can be for you, as I was in a very similar situation as a noob trying to boot into grub once. Anyway, using the bootable USB/CD you have, boot into that.

Go into the terminal and follow this website.

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please like only if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have never used that ubuntu, so it is a fresh instalation, with no data to save.

So, It is the easyest option to reinstall ubuntu.

And this time, install grub on the mbr.